# Google Maps Geocoding API not returning all results

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I was typing "macys" as the search item [in here](http://maps.google.com) (google maps website) which gives me around 30 to 40 results marked on the map.

Where as when I use their API with query term "macys" then it returns only 2 to 3 results. I am using the following api:

```
    http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=macys&sensor=false
```

I am possibly using the wrong API because it says as 'address' in the query parameter. Which API should I be using for getting all macys locations in the US / World?

I want it to return all the lat and lng objects as if its done in their own website (google maps website). If they have not exposed the API then is there a way around?

Comment: Wrong API - Use Places instead: https://developers.google.com/places/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Places API:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Geocoding is not designed to return POIs, it might return some, but you should not depend on it.

Comment: I used the [link] https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=macys&sensor=false&key=my_google_maps_key and it worked. Thanks. Folks, just make sure you have the 'PLACES API' turned ON in your API console (services section)